# How to use Count and Sum in the Same Query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, sum, aggregate

I have written the following query using the Aggregate function "SUM".

```
SELECT 
       D.PODetailID, 
       SUM(D.AcceptedQty) 
FROM STR_MRVDetail D 
INNER JOIN STR_MRVHeader H ON H.MRVID = D.MRVID 
INNER JOIN PUR_POHeader PH ON PH.POID = H.POID 
INNER JOIN PUR_PODetail PD ON PD.PODetailID = D.PODetailID
WHERE H.StatusID = 4
AND PH.POID = 839
AND (SELECT 
           SUM(AcceptedQty) 
     FROM 
           STR_MRVDetail 
     WHERE 
           STR_MRVDetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID) = 
                              (SELECT POQuantity FROM PUR_PODetail 
                               WHERE PUR_PODetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID)
                               GROUP BY D.PODetailID
```

Currently this Query returns 2 rows. I want to retrieve the count of this query. How to count the rows of the above query?

Comment: So you want to get the count (2 in this case) as a separate column?

Comment: No, I dont want to show. I just want to count the rows and to assign the rows count to an integer variable.

Comment: Your programming language should have means to get the number of retrieved rows (or just count them while you display them)

Comment: I need to get the number of retrieved rows

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your above query)`

Comment: @AbdulAhadMonty: It throws an error such as "Incorrect syntax near ')'."

Comment: sorry for that, try this.... `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your above query) as t`

Comment: @AbdulAhadMonty: I tried that too. It throws an error as "No column name was specified for column 2 of 't'."

Comment: After executing the query, the number of rows returned will be available in `@@RowCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Total_Rows
FROM
(
SELECT D.PODetailID as PODetailID, SUM(D.AcceptedQty) as Total_AcceptedQty
FROM STR_MRVDetail D 
INNER JOIN STR_MRVHeader H ON H.MRVID = D.MRVID 
INNER JOIN PUR_POHeader PH ON PH.POID = H.POID 
INNER JOIN PUR_PODetail PD ON PD.PODetailID = D.PODetailID
WHERE H.StatusID = 4
AND PH.POID = 839
AND (SELECT SUM(AcceptedQty) FROM STR_MRVDetail 
     WHERE STR_MRVDetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID) = 
     (SELECT POQuantity FROM PUR_PODetail 
      WHERE PUR_PODetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID)
GROUP BY D.PODetailID
) as t
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `@@ROWCOUNT` to the query, which also gives you the final result set as well as the count of all the rows in the result set.

```
SELECT D.PODetailID, SUM(D.AcceptedQty), @@ROWCOUNT FROM STR_MRVDetail D  
INNER JOIN STR_MRVHeader H ON H.MRVID = D.MRVID  
INNER JOIN PUR_POHeader PH ON PH.POID = H.POID  
INNER JOIN PUR_PODetail PD ON PD.PODetailID = D.PODetailID 
WHERE H.StatusID = 4 
AND PH.POID = 839 
AND (SELECT SUM(AcceptedQty) FROM STR_MRVDetail  
     WHERE STR_MRVDetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID) =  
     (SELECT POQuantity FROM PUR_PODetail  
      WHERE PUR_PODetail.PODetailID = PD.PODetailID) 
GROUP BY D.PODetailID
```